# Check for unallowed keys in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

What is the best way to check if an array contains unallowed keys ?

```
$array = array("Apple" => 33, "Orange" => 22, "Dogs" => 77,);

$allowed = array("Apple", "Orange");
```

Desired output is:

```
if (!something($array,$allowed)){echo 'Unallowed data';}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_diff_key`

```
$array = array("Apple" => 33, "Orange" => 22, "Dogs" => 77,);
$allowed = array("Apple", "Orange");
$allowed = array_flip($allowed);

$res = array_diff_key($array, $allowed);

print_r($res);

echo $allowedTxt = empty($res) ? "Allowed keys only" : "Not allowed keys";
```

`$res` contains unallowed data.

Assumes not allowed key is "`Dogs`"

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```
var_dump(array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($allowed)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_diff()` to find keys that are not allowed:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$notAllowed = array_diff($keys, $allowed);
var_dump($notAllowed); // "Dogs"
```

Here is a function that does this:

```
function something($array, $keys) {
    return ! array_diff(array_keys($array), $keys);
}
// Usage...
if ( ! something($array, $allowed)) {
    echo 'Unallowed data';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an associative (map) array for your allowed values, then you can perform the search on the allowed keys in O(*1*). With your current data structure, searching the allowed map, will take O(*n*) time.

```
$array = array("Apple" => 33, "Orange" => 22, "Dogs" => 77,);

$allowed = array("Apple" => 0, "Orange" => 1);

$found_not_allowed = 0;

foreach($array as $key => $value)
    if(!isset($allowed[$key]))
        $found_not_allowed++;

if($found_not_allowed > 0) 
    echo "Keys were found that are not allowed.";
```